# Call to WaitForSingleObject not clear in combination with CreateProcess

Tags: c++, windows, createprocess, waitforsingleobject

I came across the following code in a program that keeps track of processes:

```
void StartProcess(const std::wstring& processName, const CString& argument)
{       
    ...
    STARTUPINFO         stInfo; 
    PROCESS_INFORMATION prInfo;
    ZeroMemory( &stInfo, sizeof(stInfo) ); 
    stInfo.cb = sizeof(stInfo);
    stInfo.dwFlags=STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    stInfo.wShowWindow=SW_SHOWDEFAULT;

    bRet = CreateProcess(NULL, 
        (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)sCmdline, 
        NULL,
        NULL, 
        TRUE,
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
        NULL,
        _T("."),                         
        &stInfo, 
        &prInfo);

    // Create process has gone OK and we have to wait.
    if (bRet)
    {   
        bRet = FALSE;
        int nRetWait = WaitForSingleObject(prInfo.hProcess,0);

        if (nRetWait == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            // Get the exit code of the process
            DWORD dwExitCode = 0;
            ::GetExitCodeProcess(prInfo.hProcess, &dwExitCode);
            if (0 == dwExitCode)
            {
                // The program succeeded                    
                m_StartedServices.push_back(prInfo.dwProcessId;);
                bRet = TRUE;
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

The code should start a process and then in a later stadium terminate it (using `m_StartedServices`). However I am wondering what added value the calls to `WaitForSingleObject` and `GetExitCodeProcess` have. I have looked around a bit and it seems that the `WaitForSingleObject` with a timeout of 0 is used to check if a process is still running, but it is just created, so why check? And why check the exit code of a process that is still running?

Can anybody clear this up?

Also I found that calls:

```
CloseHandle(prInfo.hThread);
CloseHandle(prInfo.hProcess);
```

are missing in this function. Have I found a handle leak, or is there some magic that would automatically close the handles?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think this code is correct? Because, for the reasons you specify, I really don't think it is. Specifically, the second argument to `WaitForSingleObject` ought to be `INFINITE` for the code to start making some sense, but even then it doesn't (because keeping track of the ID of a process that's terminated is pointless).

Comment: Yes, it actually does what it should do (at least it starts processes). Because there is a 0 in the 'WaitForSingleObject' call the process isn't actually terminated. The call just returns immediately as stated on MSDN. However I am trying to find out if it does have some use... before I refactor it out :).

Comment: None whatsoever. Best case, this code gets extremely lucky and the process immediately terminates successfully -- so the wait immediately returns and the code gets to record the ID of a process that's terminated. Whoop de doo! Given this code, it's more likely that `m_StartedServices` is always empty, and any other code operating on it is a no-op as well.